# How expensive is it to create a new array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, buffer

Should the contents be already available as `ByteBuffer`s, how expensize is creating an array from them?

```java
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ByteBuffer buf1 = ByteBuffer.allocate(666); /*(0)*/
        ByteBuffer buf2 = ByteBuffer.allocate(666); /*(0)*/
        ByteBuffer buf3 = ByteBuffer.allocate(666); /*(0)*/
        
        ByteBuffer arr[] = new ByteBuffer[]{buf1,buf2,buf3}; /* (1) */
    }
}
```

Array creation shouldn't depend on the sizes of the buffers, right?

Comment: what type answer are you looking for?

Comment: I think it depends only on number of buffers

Comment: Object arrays in Java index _references_. So if you're asking if the size of the array in memory depends on the size of the buffers then the answer is no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array of objects in Java is actually an array of references (pointers). Conceptually, we think of the array as holding your three `ByteBuffer` objects. But actually the array holds only the equivalent of an address in memory where each `ByteBuffer` object can be found.

Accessing the array is a two-step process. When you access an element in an array, such as `arr[ 2]`, first the reference is located in that position/slot of the array. Then secondly, using that reference, the JVM jumps to the position in memory as pointed by the reference where a particular object lives.

So your array uses very little memory. The array does *not* duplicate your `ByteBuffer` objects. Before your line of code creating the array, you have three `ByteBuffer` objects floating around in memory somewhere. And after creating the array, you still have only the same three `ByteBuffer` objects floating around in memory.

By the way, the same is true if you used a `Collection` such as a `List` or `Set` rather than an array.